# Excel macro? formula? for duplicate lines

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with patient ID entries and date of blood draw and which tubes were drawn on that date. The way it's currently set up, there's a new line entry for each date (regardless of whether the patient already exists).

How can I easily "transpose" (correct word) the spreadsheet so that there is only one line per unique patient and the multiple dates are converted into additional columns instead of duplicate records?

Comment: I think there is no easy way to do this. The only way I can see this happen is creating a macro in vba to rearrange the data, but it is not going to be very easy to write a good one and will likely take some time to run, depending on the size of the table.

Comment: You are searching for a Pivot Table my friend

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @chancea, you might apply a PivotTable:

[image]

If you want actual dates in each row rather than a count to indicate which column is relevant then, in the example in E11 and copied across and down to suit:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(E3),E$2,"")
```

To compact such results you might want to select (in the example D11:L13), Copy and Paste Special..., Values (to D16) then select E16:L18 and HOME > Editing - Find & Select, Replace,  Replace with: `z`, Replace All, OK, Find what: `z`, Replace with : *nothing*, Replace All, OK followed by Find & Select, Go To Special..., check Blanks (only), Delete..., check Shift cells left, OK.